# * before iterable inside a print() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of names and I want to print each element of the list in a different line without a for loop. So, after some research I found this example: `print(*names, sep='\n')`, witch results in exactly what I want. But what does this `*` character before the list name means?

Comment: `print(*[1,2,3])` is the same as `print(1,2,3)`.

Comment: See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the official tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The * is used to unpack argument lists when calling a function. In this case it unpacks your list of names.